Cannot find module 'flowbite-react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
I am importing a component from flowbite react
import Datepicker from "flowbite-react"

But I get the following error
Cannot find module 'flowbite-react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

This is what the files look like in node_modules
These are the contents of the index.d.ts in flowbite-react/dist/types
export * from "./components/Accordion";
export * from "./components/Alert";
...
export * from "./components/Tooltip";
export * from "flowbite-react/dist/types/hooks/use-theme-mode";
export * from "./theme";
export { createTheme } from "./helpers/create-theme";
export { getTheme, getThemeMode } from "./theme-store";

What should I do to fix this error?

Components do not have default export.
Correct import:
import { Datepicker } from "flowbite-react"
